# Theme toggle button (js) does not work on very first page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a very simple GitHub page as a CV (I am not a web developer) and I have a strange issue with the behavior of website when it is loaded very first time.

I have a toggle button that switches themes to dark/light. When I visit this website very first time (or after cache a cookies clearing) I can switch to light but not back to dark (original). After refresh of website everything works just fine.

I use JS to toggle theme (but code itself does not seem to be a problem):

```
// Check the user's theme preference from local storage
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if (currentTheme) {
  body.classList.add(currentTheme);
  updateThemeLabel(currentTheme); 
}

themeToggle.addEventListener('change', () => {
  
  if (body.classList.contains('light-mode')) {
    // If the current theme is light, switch to dark
    body.classList.replace('light-mode', 'dark-mode');
    updateThemeLabel('dark-mode'); // Update the theme label text and color
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
  } else {
    // If the current theme is dark, switch to light
    body.classList.replace('dark-mode', 'light-mode');
    updateThemeLabel('light-mode'); // Update the theme label text and color
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light-mode');
  }
});

function updateThemeLabel(theme) {
  if (theme === 'dark-mode') {
    themeLabel.textContent = 'Burn your eyes';
    themeLabel.style.color = '#fff'; 
    footer.style.color = '#fff'; 
    footer.style.backgroundColor = '#333'; 
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#333'; 
    body.style.color = '#fff';
    socialIconTwitter.style.color = '#fff';
    socialIconLinkedin.style.color = '#fff';
  } else {
    themeLabel.textContent = 'Quickly back!';
    themeLabel.style.color = '#000'; 
    footer.style.color = '#000'; 
    footer.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; 
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    body.style.color = '#000';
    socialIconTwitter.style.color = '#000';
    socialIconLinkedin.style.color = '#000';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always `false`:

```
if (body.classList.contains('light-mode'))
```

Until the user selects something *and reloads the page*, at which time you set a class here:

```
body.classList.add(currentTheme);
```

But you never add that class in the `change` event handler.  Instead, you do this:

```
body.classList.replace('dark-mode', 'light-mode');
```

But if the `classList` *doesn't contain* `'dark-mode'` then there's nothing to replace.

Instead, remove and add the classes.  For example:

```
themeToggle.addEventListener('change', () => {
  
  if (body.classList.contains('light-mode')) {
    body.classList.remove('light-mode'); // remove light mode
    body.classList.add('dark-mode'); // add dark mode
    updateThemeLabel('dark-mode');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('dark-mode'); // remove dark mode
    body.classList.add('light-mode'); // add light mode
    updateThemeLabel('light-mode');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light-mode');
  }
});
```